# Sketch: how to create colour palette in symbols page

Tags: color, sketching

I'm new to the Mac app Sketch, and I've been watching a few tutorials where a color palette (a grid of colored rectangles) is created on the symbols page, and a color from the palette is assigned to an element of a symbol, meaning that whenever the color is updated, all instances of the symbol have the element's color updated.

I want to know if a color is a special symbols page component.

In the example above, how is the link between the color in the palette and the element in the symbol made?

What do I need to do to be able to select a color from the palette on the symbols page, and be able to assign it as the color of an element on my canvas?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for color symbols to update other components when the symbol's colors are updated themselves, you'll have to include the color symbol **within** these other components.  For example, if you're creating a rectangular button, instead of setting the background color using the inspector's color picker in the right sidebar, you'd want to add your **color symbol** in the background of the button, and then potentially create a mask using the shape layer of the button.

It's kind of hard to explain this in text, but Pablo Stanley's "Sketch Together" YouTube channel has an [excellent example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bjqVF7Fvg4&index=21&list=PLWlUJU11tp4fEXI8deWhBQAHDv9R23WHB) of how to accomplish this in the context of creating a button system.

That being said, it is now recommended to use **layer styles** to accomplish this same behavior, as of Sketch 52.  The above method was created because layer styles weren't previously supported within nested symbols, but with this new version of Sketch, layer styles can now be swapped within symbols.  [Sketch's documentation](https://sketchapp.com/docs/styling/shared-styles/) covers this new functionality.

I hope this helps!

Comment: So a color is just a symbol, and a symbol is just a piece of content with styling information. So when you apply the color symbol as the background color say, it just grabs whatever styling information from the color symbol which is relevant to the background color?

Comment: And when you create the color symbol, you save it as something like palette/warning, palette/success, so that warning and palette can be selected as sub-items of palette. Neat!

Comment: That video was excellent thank you Zack. For the record, the juicy bits started at 0:14.